# JQuery Select function for highlighting current element

Tags: jquery, css, select

I have a series of buttons functioning similar to tabs but taking use of JQuery load.

The button that is the one currently selected I want to have a different CLASS. When another element is selected I want the class of the previous one returned to its previous class.

The CLASS set to all buttons is .TABlink which is used as a selector for them in the load script. The CLASS that governs what each of these links does is in a surrounding span.

Overview

```
    <span class="TABbase"><a href="?accommodation" class="TABlink" onclick="return false">Accommodation</a></span> 

    <span class="TABbase"><a href="<?travel" class="TABlink" onclick="return false">Travel</a></span>
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0):

The setting of the selected class is easy:

```
//bind each 'button' so that on click, it is styled to be 'selected'
$('.TABlink').click(function(){select($(this))});

//Applies the selected style to the element
function select(el){
    $(el).addClass('.TABselected');
}
```

I can think of two ways of deselecting:

1. Remove the selected class from *all* elements before setting it for the currently selected 'button'.

   ```
   function deselectAll(){
       $('.TABlink').removeClass('.TABselected');
   }
   ```

   Here's a [fiddle showing this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/UeGdX/).
2. Keep track of the last button selected and deselect it when a different button is clicked. <strike>This might be too much work for a simple application.</strike>
   **Update** I'm still getting my head around closures so I wasn't sure how you would do this without maintaining and checking a global variable but I took another shot at it today and I think I've got something decent. You can check it out [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/UeGdX/2/). here's the code:

   ```
   var select = (function(){
   //variable to store last selected 'button'
   var selected;

   return function (el){
           //selected is still accessible because of closure
           if(selected){
               $(selected).removeClass('TABselected');
           }
           $(el).addClass('TABselected');
           selected = el; //save this as the last selected
         }
   })();

   //bind each 'button' so that on click, it is styled to be 'selected'
   $('.TABlink').click(function(){select($(this))});
   ```

Comment: I don't think this will work, since `this` would be scoped to whatever `this` is when `$('.TABlink').click(...)` is called.

I think you want to call `$(this)` in the `select` function to get the element that the event was triggered on.

Comment: @partkyle `this` *will* refer to the element that the event was triggered on. The call to `click` will only set the click handler for all elements that were selected - the handler will then get the element that is actually clicked through `this`. Check out the fiddle I linked to. However, your comment did make me realize I had some other errors in the code I'd put in - I've corrected those now.

Comment: @Drackir Thanks, thought I'd caught the last of those!

Comment: No problem. You missed a quote in the second example too. :) Also, why create the `select` function at all? You can just call that code directly in the callback function. In fact, I just noticed that because of the way you've done it, you actually wrap the element with jQuery TWICE. `$(this)` gets passed in as `el` and then you do `$(el)`. Why not just: `$('.TABlink').click(function(){$(this).addClass('.TABselected');});`?

Comment: Argh! Fixed. I usually just wrap the element in jQuery always - don't you just get back the same jQuery object if what you passed in to `$()` is already a jQuery object? I need to check out how much of impact this has on performance. Also, the aim of having the `select` function was to make things clearer (hopefully) and also, that's where the call to `deselectAll()` goes, if you choose to use the first option I suggested. Although, you could just have the anonymous click handler do all of it...